# Fix UIBarButtonItem with image to bottom toolbar iOS 7 App

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

In my iOS application i have a `UITextView` in the center of a `UIToolbar`, an `UIImage` on the left of the `UITextView` and a Button on the right of the `UITextView`. This is my code:

```
UIBarButtonItem *sendButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Send" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"smile.png"];
image = [image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
UIBarButtonItem *smile = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:image style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
UIBarButtonItem *textview = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:_newMessageTextView];
newMessageToolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: smile, textview, sendButton, nil];
```

This is the result:

[image]

My problem is when i'm going to write multiline text. While the button is fixed to the `UIToolbar`'s bottom, the `UIImage` moves in the center vertically:

[image]

I don't understand why this happens, i'd like to have the `UIImage` fixed to the bottom too. How can i solve this?

Comment: first you try with image instead of barbutton what is happen either it's goes down or still as center

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your _newMessageTextView's text change delegate method, when input text modify height of textView, add following code to adjust UIBarButtonItem smile's imageInsets:

```
UIBarButtonItem *smile = [newMessageToolbar.items objectAtIndex:0];

 [smile setImageInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, (/* Calculate bottom inset value*/)*-1, 0)];
```